# C++ std::map look for values but not keys

Tags: find, stdmap

I have a std::map which maps a structure to a string:

```
struct st
{
 std::string name;
 int         age;
}

std::map<st, std::string>                      m_SoundStructList;
```

Now I want to look in the map based on a string which is the name and get the structure.

```
std::string lName="Kate"
auto iter = m_SoundStructList.find(lName);
st lStruct=it->fisrt;
```

Now it is only possible for me to apply find on structure but the strings.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have to iterate through the map and use the matching element manually.

For C++11 it would be

```
for(const auto& p : m_SoundStructList) {
    if (p.second.name == "Kate") {
        // Do something
    }
}
```